# How to get logical drivers from a client machine with asp

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

A tester came up to me and told me that a link was creating a dialog with the logical drivers from the server and the desired behavior would be that it showed drivers from the client side.

Since c# is a server side language I only believed that I need to use a client-side language.
Today this application is developed in Asp Net MVC so I went to seach such a feature in asp net.

Turns out there is nothing related to that I could find.
I found that javascript provides "FileSystemObject" that I believe I could do that, but I am looking for a solution using asp.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIC, you cannot do this in C#. Software running on your server has no way to access the file system of the client computer. So you *do* need a client-side language such as JavaScript.

So I would try to get more information from JavaScript people, but I strongly suspect that there are severe limitations on this if it's possible at all. I don't want every website I visit to be able to access my system drives. It's a security risk.

Comment: You are right. The only viable way to do that is to use input type file from html and I found many plug-ins to get the job done covering  many situations. Found this nice one to use with ajax: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload#download